# Quick Sort function C++ 1 parameter - vector

Tags: c++, quicksort

I need help implementing the [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm in C++. I am limited to passing in just one parameter, a vector. I have this code so far but it is not working because it says there is an error with the copy function. Please help me fix this. Thank you.

```
template <class T>
vector<T> quickSort(vector<T> lst)
{
    double i = 0;
    double j = lst.size() - 2;
    double temp;
    int pivotIndex = lst.size() - 1;
    double pivot = lst[pivotIndex];

    if (lst.size() <= 1)
    {
        return lst;
    }

    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (lst[i] < pivot)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (lst[j] > pivot)
            j--;

        if (i <= j)
        {
            temp = lst[i];
            lst[i] = lst[j];
            lst[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    lst[pivotIndex] = lst[i];
    lst[i] = pivot;
    pivotIndex = i;

    if (lst.size() <= 2)
        return lst;

    vector<T> left_vec, right_vec;

    vector<double>::iterator pivotIter = lst.begin() + pivotIndex;
    copy(lst.begin(), pivotIter, back_inserter(left_vec));
    copy(pivotIter + 1, lst.end(), back_inserter(right_vec));

    if (left_vec.size() > 0)
    {
        quickSort(left_vec);
        copy(left_vec.begin(), left_vec.end(), lst.begin());
    }

    if (right_vec.size() > 0)
    {
        quickSort(right_vec);
        copy(right_vec.begin(), right_vec.end(), pivotIter + 1);
    }

    return lst;
}
```

Comment: `quickSort(left_vec);` is a no-op.

Comment: Normally, one would create another function that contains the indexes or iterators to sort against and recurse on those. Like `void quicksort(start_iter, end_iter)` dividing into smaller vectors is quite inefficient.

Comment: quicksort is an *in-place*  algorithm. This is not quicksort. You can't implement quicksort with only the collection as parameter.

Comment: What are those `double`s doing there? Your elements are `T`, and indexes are integers.

Comment: Please post your actual error along with your question. If you're limited to only passing one argument i.e. `std::vector` then you need to pass it by reference. The function header would look like this `void  quickSort(vector<T>& lst)`. Observe the `void` return-type. Your algorithm will sort the vector in-place and you don't need to return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things wrong with you implementation. Firstly, `vector<T>::iterator` is a dependent. So, use `typename` before that. See [c++ dependents](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name). Next, your vector indexes should be integers `(i and j)` and you can use template argument `T` instead of `double` for `temp` and `pivot` as I believe you intention was to make it generic.

Finally while performing the left and right quick sort, overwrite you `left_vec` and `right_vec`. Although I prefer pass by reference.

Also, the copy operation that you are performing is effectively increasing your quick sort's time complexity. Since you are allowed to pass only one parameter, cross check your problem statement whether you can use any global variables or pass a `struct` with vector, low and high indexes.

Corrected implementation.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// should be avoided in general.
using namespace std;

template <class T>
vector<T> quickSort(vector<T> lst)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = lst.size() - 2;
    T temp;
    int pivotIndex = lst.size() - 1;
    T pivot = lst[pivotIndex];

    if (lst.size() <= 1)
    {
        return lst;
    }

    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (lst[i] < pivot)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (lst[j] > pivot)
            j--;

        if (i <= j)
        {
            temp = lst[i];
            lst[i] = lst[j];
            lst[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    lst[pivotIndex] = lst[i];
    lst[i] = pivot;
    pivotIndex = i;

    if (lst.size() <= 2)
        return lst;

    vector<T> left_vec, right_vec;

    typename vector<T>::iterator pivotIter = lst.begin() + pivotIndex;
    copy(lst.begin(), pivotIter, back_inserter(left_vec));
    copy(pivotIter + 1, lst.end(), back_inserter(right_vec));

    if (left_vec.size() > 0)
    {
        left_vec = quickSort(left_vec);
        copy(left_vec.begin(), left_vec.end(), lst.begin());
    }

    if (right_vec.size() > 0)
    {
        right_vec = quickSort(right_vec);
        copy(right_vec.begin(), right_vec.end(), pivotIter + 1);
    }

    return lst;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a{11, 8, 30, 21, 1, 5, 2};

    vector<int> res = quickSort(a);

    for(int  i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
        cout<<res[i]<<" ";

    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```